# DataType Editor Template not working for created DOM elements

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have a page for editing classes.  On this page is a section wher eyou can add and remove class events dynamically on the page.  My problem is in this section one of the things that comes up is a date.  I want to just show the Date section not the time as well.  Here is the class set up for Entity Framework.

```
public class ClassEvent
{
    public ClassEvent()
    {
        EventDate = DateTime.Today;
    }
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    public DateTime? EventDate { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a class")]
    public int ClassID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Class")]
    [ForeignKey("ClassID")]
    public virtual ScheduledClass ScheduledClass { get; set; }

    public Boolean Delete { get; set; }
}
```

I have this code as an editor template for datetime objects.

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<System.DateTime?> 

@Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:d}", Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") :""), new { @class = "datefield", style="width:100px"})
```

I have another field in the actual scheduledclass class that is shown below

```
public class ScheduledClass
{
    public ScheduledClass()
    {
        Attendees = new List<ClassAttendee>();
    }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a topic")]
    public int ClassTopicID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Topic")]
    public virtual ClassTopic ClassTopic { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int ClassTypeID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Class Type")]
    public virtual ClassType ClassType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Class Date")] 
    public DateTime ClassDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Attendees")] 
    public virtual ICollection<ClassAttendee> Attendees { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Events")]
    public virtual ICollection<ClassEvent> ClassEvents { get; set; }
}
```

The editor template works fine for the ClassDate when the page is loaded but in the page if I click the button to add a class event the editor template is not applied to what is created.  Here is the editor template for the ClassEvent itself

```
@model TRIOSoftware.Domain.Entities.ClassEvent

<tr class="ClassEvent">
<td>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ClassID )
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Description, new {style ="width:125px"})
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
</td>
<td>    
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EventDate, new { @class = "datefield", style = "width:150px" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EventDate)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Delete, new { @class = "mark-for-delete" })
    @Html.LinkToRemoveNestedForm("Remove", "tr.ClassEvent", "input.mark-for-delete")
</td>
</tr>
```

Has anyone run into this issue before?

Comment: Try decorating the property with this as well:  `[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]`

Comment: I did add this but I still get the same result the textbox shows the date and time together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being I was using TextBoxFor and I needed to be using EditorFor to get it to find my Editor Template